# Initialize MPI cluster using Rmpi

Tags: r, mpi, qsub, snow

Recently I try to make use of the department cluster to do parallel computing in `R`. The cluster system is manged by `SGE`. `OpenMPI` has been installed and passed the installation test.

I submit my query to the cluster via `qsub` command. In the script, I specify the number of node I want to use via the following command. 
`#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=24` `(two nodes with 24 threads each)`
Then, `mpirun -np 1 R --slave -f test.R`
I have checked `$PBS_NODEFILE` afterwards. Two nodes are allocated as I wish. I could find two nodes' names `node1, node2` and each of them appears 24 times.

The content of ``test.R` is listed as follows.

```
library(Rmpi)
library(snow)

cl <- makeCluster(41,type="MPI")
clusterCall(cl, function() Sys.info()[c("nodename","machine")])
stopCluster(cl)
mpi.quit()
```

The output of `clusterCall()` is quite disappointing. There is only one node's name `node1` which appears 41 times. This is definitely wrong since there are only 24 threads on `node1`. It seems that my `R` script only finds one node or even one thread out of it. I just wonder what is the right way to construct a `MPI` cluster?

Comment: Your cluster is managed by either PBSPro or Torque. Although many commands in SGE are named the same (`qsub`, `qstat`, etc.), SGE doesn't use the `#PBS` sentinel but rather `#$` and the environment variables it exports start with `SGE_`.

Comment: Your script and launch commands work for me with LSF. Make sure the MPI library is getting the environment properly. Run the following from within the batch script: `mpiexec hostname` and see if it outputs the same hostnames and the same number of times as is contained in `$PBS_NODEFILE`. There could be a problem with the integration between Open MPI and PBS/Torque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your cluster is definitely not managed by SGE even if the latter is installed. SGE doesn't understand the `#PBS` sentinel in the job files and it doesn't export the `PBS_NODEFILE` environment variable (most environment variables that SGE exports start with `SGE_`). It also won't accept the `nodes=2:ppn=24` resource request as the distribution of the slots among the allocated nodes is controlled by the specified parallel environment. What you have is either PBS Pro or Torque. But SGE names the command line utilities the same and `qsub` takes more or less the same arguments, which probably is why you think it is SGE that you have.

The problem you describe usually occurs if Open MPI is not able to properly obtain the node list from the environment, e.g. if it wasn't compiled with support for PBS Pro/Torque. In that case, it will start all MPI processes on the node on which `mpirun` was executed. Check that the proper RAS module was compiled by running:

```
ompi_info | grep ras
```

It should list the various RAS modules and among them should be one called `tm`:

```
...
MCA ras: tm (MCA v2.0, API v2.0, Component v1.6.5)
...
```

If the `tm` module is not listed, then Open MPI will not automatically obtain the node list and the hostfile must be explicitly specified:

```
mpiexec ... -machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE ...
```

Under PBS Pro/Torque, Open MPI also needs the `tm` PLM module. The lack of that module will prevent Open MPI from using the TM API to remotely launch the processes on the second node and it will therefore fall back to using SSH. In such case, you should make sure that passwordless SSH login, e.g. one using public key authentication, is possible from each cluster node into each other node.

Your first step in solving the issue is to check for the presence of the correct modules as shown above. If the modules are there, you should launch `hostname` under `mpiexec` and check if that works, e.g.:

```
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=24

echo "Allocated nodes:"
cat $PBS_NODEFILE
echo "MPI nodes:"
mpiexec --mca ras_base_display_alloc 1 hostname
```

then compare the two lists and also examine the `ALLOCATED NODES` block. The lists should be more or less equal and both nodes should be shown in the allocated nodes table with 24 slots per node (cf. `Num slots`). If the second list contains only one hostname, then Open MPI is not able to properly obtain the hostfile because something is preventing the `tm` modules (given that they do exist) from initialising or being selected. This could either be the system-wide Open MPI configuration or some other RAS module having higher priority. Passing `--mca ras_base_verbose 10` to `mpiexec` helps in determining if that is the case.

Comment: Great answer ! It turns out that Open MPI didn't obtain the node list appropriately. This is mainly due to the permission issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `-np 1` part of your `mpirun` invocation instructs MPI to use only one core. Try removing that part so that OpenMPI gets the number of core from the environment set by SGE.

Comment: Open MPI always receives the full slot allocation information from the DRM environment. `-np 1` only instructs it to use a single slot for launching the initial MPI job.

Comment: I agree with `@HristoIliev`. There are discussions about this `-np` options. Thanks anyway.